# NSXPCInterface setClasses causes "Lazily named class 0x600000xxxxxx wasn’t named by lazy name handler" on Xcode 14+ Swift @objc enum

Tags: swift, cocoa, xpc, nsxpcconnection

After updating to Xcode 14 I am getting the `SIGABRT` crash "Lazily named class 0x600000dc6520 wasn’t named by lazy name handler". In the latest version of Xcode 13 it compiles and runs without any flaw. The only thing different from the very basic is that I use the `MyAppSharedObjects` to get across more complex objects between the XPC Service and the main app. Apart from that it doesn't look like anything beyond tutorial level `NSXPCInterface` code to me:

```
import MyAppScriptSandbox
import MyAppSharedObjects
import Foundation

class ScriptExecutor {
    init?() {
        let incomingClasses = NSSet(array: [
            NSArray.self,
            NSString.self,
            NSValue.self,
            NSNumber.self,
            NSData.self,
            NSDate.self,
            NSNull.self,
            NSURL.self,
            NSUUID.self,
            NSError.self,
            NSDictionary.self,
            ScriptSandboxReply.self,
            AppleScriptError.self,
            AppleScriptErrorType.self
        ]) as Set

        let remoteInterface = NSXPCInterface(with: MyAppScriptSandboxProtocol.self)
        remoteInterface.setClasses( // **** CRASH HAPPENS HERE ****
            incomingClasses,
            for: #selector(MyAppScriptSandboxProtocol.execute(script:withReply:)),
            argumentIndex: 0,
            ofReply: true
        )

import Foundation
import MyAppSharedObjects

@objc
public protocol MyAppScriptSandboxProtocol {
    func execute(
        script: String,
        withReply reply: @escaping (ScriptSandboxReply) -> Void
    )
    func terminate()
}

@objc(ScriptSandboxReply)
public class ScriptSandboxReply: NSObject, NSSecureCoding {
    public static let supportsSecureCoding = true

    public func encode(with coder: NSCoder) {
        // Removed company specific code
    }

    required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        // Removed company specific code
    }
}
```

This data type was the issue:

```
@objc(AppleScriptErrorType)
public enum AppleScriptErrorType: Int {
    case error
    case noResult
    case errorNorResult // This really shouldn't happen IRL

    static let key = "AppleScriptErrorType"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lazily named class wasn't named by lazy name handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64885907/lazily-named-class-wasnt-named-by-lazy-name-handler)

Comment: Basically accepted answer in above question is the most helpful thing you can have. Something is wrong with `@objc` generation, probably of the `@objc public protocol MyAppScriptSandboxProtocol`, or maybe some other part. So you will need to dig into generated objc code and see differences. And to do that you need to read what lazy class is - which is well explained in that accepted answer

Comment: @rapiddevice thank you for your help, I already found and upvoted that excellent and underrated answer. However that didn't fix my issue. I did manage to fix it myself, I'll update my question and answer it myself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of dabbing I found the issue. I started to comment out custom data types in the `incomingClasses` list and while the application crashed upon the first received message it stopped crashing on init. By uncommenting the custom data types one by one I finally found the culprit:

```
@objc(AppleScriptErrorType)
public enum AppleScriptErrorType: Int {
    case error
    case noResult
    case errorNorResult // This really shouldn't happen IRL

    static let key = "AppleScriptErrorType"
}
```

I have no idea why this perfectly sane enum type could not be transferred anymore after Xcode 14 dropped while it worked in Xcode 13.4.1, I think it might be an Apple bug. However I could get on with my life using the `rawValue` (so just the `int` value really) to send the value from one side and to reconstruct the `AppleScriptErrorType` `enum` on the receiving side.